# Quiero modificar una matriz pero no puedo

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Quiero modificar la matriz creada en arr por columna(la que el usuario quiera) y por fila(la que el usuario quiera) ingresando el valor que quiera:

```
from numpy import *
arr = zeros((2,2))
for j in arr:
    for k in j:
        k = 5
print arr
```

Comment: el codigo que esta ahi no funciona

Comment: ¿Cómo lees la columna y fila de la matriz que se debe modificar?, y ¿cómo obtiene el nuevo valor del elemento en el array?

Comment: Quieres cambiar solo un elemento de la matriz a la vez? o toda la matriz con el valor que el usuario ingrese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from numpy import *
arr = zeros((2,2))
for j in range(len(arr)):
    for k in range(len(arr[j])):
        arr[j][k] = 5

print(arr)
```

El funcionamiento de **`range(n)`** es genera una lista de **`n`**(1, 2, 3, etc) valores para poder iterar sobre ella.

Con **`len(objeto)`** obtienes el tamaño de la lista o cadena.

`for j in range(len(arr)):`
Genera la lista de tamaño igual al de arr (2) e itera sobre ella.

`j` es igual a la posición actual en la lista.

`for k in range(len(arr[j])):` Obtiene el tamaño de la lista que esta dentro
             de la primera lista `len(arr[j])` e itera nuevamente en ella.

`k` es igual a la posición actual en la lista.

`arr[j][k] = 5` Entonces accedemos a la primera lista `arr[j]` y después tenemos que ir por la
             por el valor que esta en la segunda lista que esta dentro de la primera `arr[j][k]`

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo y también me enseño te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1):

La asignación directa dentro de un `for-in` no funciona en Python ni tampoco en NumPy. Necesitas usar indices para hacer eso:

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.zeros((2,2))

for j in np.arange(arr.shape[0]):
    for k in np.arange(arr.shape[1]):
        arr[j, k] = 5
```

Otra opción es usar `np.ndenumerate`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((2,2))
for (i, j), valor in np.ndenumerate(arr):
        arr[i, j] = 5
```

Ya que estas usando NumPy, deberias usar sus métodos (`narange`, `array.shape`, etc) de forma preferente por eficiencia y simplificación del propio código.

Si quisieras cambiar **todos** los valores del array a la vez por un número ingresado por el usuario entonces no necesitarías ningún ciclo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.zeros((2,2))
>>> arr.fill(5)
>>> print(arr) 
[[ 5.  5.]
 [ 5.  5.]]
```

No uses `from módulo import *` como forma de importar en Python, eso es peligroso y una mala práctica ya que puedes terminar sobreescribiendo funciones/métodos del módulo sin darte cuenta llevando a errores inesperados y difíciles de rastrear (más aún en bibliotecas complejas y extensas como NumPy, Pandas, SciPy, etc). Usa en su lugar alguna de estas fórmulas: `import numpy`, `import numpy as np` o `from numpy import zeros, arange...`.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte y por lo de "import *" que es una mala práctica lo corregire